# How to enlarge the active Entry field ( Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to enlarge the active Entry field. Active - a place that will trigger the activation of this place after pressing

[image: Example image]

Comment: Did one solution help you, please upvote and accept as helpful answer... https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the new Visual State Manager for Xamarin Forms 3.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager
It allows you to style your entry for different states. The common states are `Normal`, `Focused`, `Disabled`.
You can e.g. increase the `FontSize` and do stuff with other states as well. (have a look at the given link)

Your desired state is `Focused`.

```
<Entry FontSize="18">
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Lime" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Pink" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scale method to increase the size of the Entry.Every view has the property Scale which can be used to increase the size;

```
entry.Scale =2;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to achieve that.

One of them is changing positional properties, like `Margin`:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Entry">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,30,30,30"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="icon"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Silver">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
               x:Name="txtName"
               Placeholder="Name"
               Focused="GrowEntry"
               Unfocused="ShrinkEntry"/>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
               x:Name="txtEmail"
               Placeholder="E-mail"
               BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
               Focused="GrowEntry"
               Unfocused="ShrinkEntry"/>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
               x:Name="txtPassword"
               Placeholder="Password"
               Focused="GrowEntry"
               Unfocused="ShrinkEntry"/>
    </Grid>
    <BoxView Color="White"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

And in the code behind, the `GrowEntry` and `ShrinkEntry`:

```
private void GrowEntry(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var entry = (Entry)sender;

    entry.Margin = new Thickness(6, 12, 12, 12);
}

private void ShrinkEntry(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var entry = (Entry)sender;

    entry.Margin = new Thickness(20, 30, 30, 30);
}
```

You'll get something like that:

[image: Using Example]